# If $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then $i \notin K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to prove that if $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then $i \notin K$.

What I have tried: assume $i \in K$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(i) \subseteq K$ and since $4=[K : \mathbb{Q}]=[K\colon \mathbb{Q}(i)][\mathbb{Q}(i)\colon \mathbb{Q}]=2 [K \colon \mathbb{Q}(i)]$, it follows that $K/\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is Galois (being a quadratic extension) and $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}(i)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

If I pick a non-trivial automorphism of $K$ fixing  $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, what would that automorphism look like? I feel like knowing that might be half the way to getting a contradiction. I can't think of a way to move forward and would appreciate some help, please.

Comment: Remember that if $F/K$ is a quadratic extension, then $F=K(\sqrt{q})$ for some $q\in K$, so the non-trivial automorphism of $F$ fixing $K$ is the map $a+b\sqrt{q}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: Try and show that if $i\in K$ then every element of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ has order two

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks. I can see that this automorphism must be a generator of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}(i))$. Do you know if this will give a contradiction like  $\mathbb{Q}(i) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $i\in K$. Suppose the group $\{\mathrm{id}, \sigma\}$ fix the field $\mathbb{Q}(i).$ Let $\tau$ be the complex conjugation. $\sigma, \tau$ are distinct elements of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, both of which has order 2. But $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ does not have two different elements of order 2.

Comment: Can you explain why $\sigma$ and $\tau$ have to be distinct?

Comment: @JohnSmith Because $\sigma$ fixes $i$ and $\tau$ doesn't.